# Physics question about Impulse and Force, please!

Tags: physics

We're out currently because of Coronavirus so all of my assignments are online because we're stuck inside. I was struggling before when I had a teacher, but I'm really struggling now without. He's linking most of our assignments to this site called Physicsclassroom. I can probably do the majority on my own, but I need help getting there with explanations. Being limited, there's only so many options i have as to get help on them. Please, if there's anyone that can help, I'd *greatly* appreciate it. Thank you.

[image]

The options are  $\Delta V$, Time, or Mass for the first one. After that, they're either of the cases: case A or case B.

[Physics homework example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KAXw.png)

Comment: try to ask physics questions on the physics page of stackexchange

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

In first question, the time of collision is given to be same, the mass cannot change during a collision (conservation of mass), so it is the velocity that changes (which it clearly changes from 18$\hat{i}$ to $-6\hat{i}$, and 18$\hat{i}$ to 0 as given)
So $\Delta v$ is the correct option here.

The momentum change in Case A is $\Delta \overrightarrow{p} = m(\overrightarrow{v_{final}}-\overrightarrow{v_{initial}} )= 1200(-6\hat{i} -18\hat{i})=1200(-24\hat{i}) $

In case B,  $\Delta \overrightarrow{p} = m(\overrightarrow{v_{final}}-\overrightarrow{v_{initial}} )= 1200(0 -18\hat{i})=1200(-18\hat{i}) $

So for the second question, case A has larger momentum change.

For third question, by the impulse momentum theorem (Impulse = change in momentum), Case A has larger impulse recieved on the car.

Lastly, Impulse is nothing but force times the time of collision, so force will also be larger in case A (as the time of collision is same)

BTW, try to ask questions that involve purely physics on the physics page of stack exchange: [Link to the Physics Page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)